# Changing a fill color on ellipse using Objective-C

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am overriding drawRect method in order to draw ellipse

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor mainColorYellow].CGColor);

CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0.0, 2.0, rect.size.width , rect.size.height - 4.0);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

}

How can I change fill color on ellipse? I tried using `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(CGContextRef c, CGColorRef color)` but without result.

Comment: You are only stroking the path. You need to fill it.

Answer (score 4):

There is two different operations, fill and stroke. Stroke es the border, fill is the inside. You are only doing the border. You can control the fill and border color independently. You have, however, to render both explicitly. For example:

```
[[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 2.0, rect.size.width , rect.size.height - 4.0)];
path.lineWidth  = 2.0;        
[path fill];
[path stroke];
```

Notice I wrote the code in a more modern quartz. The context is implicit. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below:

```
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
```